# Is it possible to collapse the file tree in Cloud9?

Tags: cloud9-ide

In the c9 editor is there a way to toggle/collapse the work-space file tree, preferably by using a keyboard shortcut?

I know that this is possible for a terminal console but was hoping the same for the file tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For collapse:

1. Click on the folder that you want to collapse in the Tree:

[image: Tree]

2. Then <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd>:

[image: Tree-collapse]